# Are there any Pokemon cards banned in unlimited format?

Tags: pokemon

The [Pokemon website](https://www.pokemon.com/us/play-pokemon/about/pokemon-tcg-banned-card-list) says that no cards are banned in unlimited format. Is this true? Are cards such as [_____’s Pikachu](https://pkmncards.com/card/_____s-pikachu-wizards-black-star-promos-24/) or [Ancient Mew](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Ancient_Mew_(The_Power_of_One_promo)) banned? What about jumbo cards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlimited format has no official tournaments, so it doesn't get much attention from Pokémon.  However, the general statement that no cards are banned is correct, though with some caveats as below.

Jumbo cards are banned in tournaments per a [ruling in the Compendium](https://compendium.pokegym.net/ruling/1740/):

> No, you cannot. You may only use cards that have been released for TCG play in the standard size. Jumbo cards are artistic representations of the legal card's art.

___'s Pikachu *is* legal to play in the Unlimited format.

Ancient Mew would be illegal due to the different card back.

Comment: Are the only banned cards ones with different backs or different sizes?

Comment: Where the ruling about a different card back being illegal? [Bulbagarden](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Ancient_Mew_(The_Power_of_One_promo)) says Ancient Mew is banned because of the unreadable Runic, and also says that _____'s Pikachu is banned, and [says](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/%27s_Pikachu_(Wizards_Promo_24)): "Both Japanese prints have the clause '(This card cannot be used at official tournaments)' to the right of the illustrator name". I would post an answer, but I don't have more official references.

Comment: Same back is more of a common sense thing - it is referenced in some rulings, but not explicitly in the rules.  (Again, this is really a "tournament" ruling, which ... may or may not make sense for the context of this question, but there's nothing *better* really.) ___'s Pikachu doesn't have that text in English, and so I don't see why it wouldn't be legal in Unlimited formats here (but again there are no official Unlimited tournaments).

Comment: I'd also note that Bulbapedia seems to be referencing Wizards rulings, which are not necessarily valid any longer (Wizards hasn't controlled the game for twenty years now.). In fact, Ancient Mew was legal in *Standard* in Japan for a while (but never in the TPCi regions.)

Comment: @Joe For what it's worth, and it's probably not worth much, since what applies to one game obviously doesn't say much about what applies to others, but Magic The Gathering has tournament-legal double-faced and meld cards that don't have card "backs" (requiring sleeves or helper cards if you want to play with them). Although they haven't otherwise changed their card backs (apart from contraptions and attractions, which don't go in your regular deck and are part of non-tournament-legal sets in any case).

Comment: Yeah, this actually changes when TPC took over Pokémon TCG from Wizards, the first publisher of the Pokémon TCG!